# Extension methods for sealed class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have this `sealed` class,

```
public sealed class A
{
    public string AName {get;set;}
}
```

and someone can write an extension method for it like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static void ExtensionMethodForA (this A a)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("A's Extension method!");
   }
}
```

The question is, how do you prevent that ?

Comment: You can't prevent it - there's no keyword to put on your class to stop this feature. If you have a class - someone can write an extension method for it. But **why** is this such a problem? What are you trying to prevent others from doing ?

Comment: @marc_s: I am giving out my custom helper library online. But, what if some body writes some `un-wanted` extension methods, create a wrapper of the dll and then give out an entirely different dll ?

Comment: This feature cannot be 'disabled'. If you are giving out your library online, maybe this is the case to protect it, signing it and using obfuscation, if possible.

Comment: You have created a public class. You intend users to be able to consume it. You don't have control over what users do with it / how they wrap it. You can stop people DERIVING from it (using sealed), but extending with extension methods isn't actually doing anything other than making a static method call look prettier. If you provide users with a class, there is never anything to stop them from wrapping all your classes in their own classes, adding extra functions, and releasing a new DLL.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: who gets to decide what an *unwanted* extension method is????

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't. You can't. And you shouldn't want to.

Instance methods are always preferred to extension methods, so it should not present a conflict. Other than that, they are mere syntax / convenience. Stop trying to make life inconvenient for callers.

Comment: :Thanks marc. But, my concern is: " I am giving out my custom helper library online. But, what if some body writes some un-wanted extension methods, create a wrapper of the dll and then give out an entirely different dll ?"

Comment: +1. @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. - your concern sounds like "what if someone actually use my library"... or I'm missing something?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed "unwanted" - by who? if somebody created the extension method, it must by definition be "wanted". Also, they would need to deploy both the original dll and the dll that declares the extension methods. It is not clear what your concern is.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. If you're in a position where users are using code from an untrustworthy source you've already lost; end of story.  They can do whatever malicious actions they want, and the time to stop them has already past.  It's like trying to inhibit the permissions of the admin user in the event that the admin account is hacked.  It's simply too late by that point.

Comment: I think nowhewhomustnotbenamed should be directed toward signing his assembly.  You asked `"unwanted" - by who?` but imagine a hacker who adds a bunch of spyware extension methods and then re-releases the dll.  I think we can agree that these extension methods are unwanted.

Comment: @Ben signed or unsigned doesn't matter; assembly signing is not a security feature. If somebody can get a dodgy dll onto your machine, they can also suppress assembly signature checks.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes marc I know signing is not a security feature.  However, it sounded to me like the OP was putting his dll library on the internet for his customers to download, so signing would help his customers to be more sure that the dll came from him and did not contain any unwanted methods.  I think this is what he is worried about.  Its not about somebody else getting a dodgy dll on to your machine, its about his customers making sure they are not putting a dodgy dll on their own machines.

Answer (score 7):

You might be confused by the term "extension method". It is not a *method in the class* or even a derived class; It is an *operation on a type.* It has no access to the private, protected or internal members of the class hierarchy and therefore the class is still sealed.

So, you can't and don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

There would be no point. Any user could still create a static class which implemented a method which used your class type.

They would just leave out the 'this' out of the declaration, and callers would have to explicitly pass the object, rather than using the simpler . syntax. The end result would be identical.

Extension methods are just a nicer way of expressing what I've just described, which will always be possible anyway.