# Internal class masked by object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

Assume that class (B)'s public function has the return line:

```
return (object)(new List<A>{Some elements})
```

where A is an internal and sealed class. I cannot change the code of A or B.

After I call this function in B, how do I find the first element of that list. C# does not let me cast that list back into `List<A>` because A is internal.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the method signature of the public method in B that returns the list?

Comment: @Andrey "After I call this function in B, how do I find the first element of that list."

Comment: @adv12 public object Foo()

Answer (score 2):

1. Just because you can read the source code or disassemble the code, you should not rely on the current implementation, rather try to use the public interface.
2. `List<A>` implements the non-generic `IList`, so you can cast back to `IEnumerable` or `IList` if you really look for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast a generic List to the non-generic IEnumerable, iterate over that, and then use Object.ToString() to get information about the B instances, or you can just return the reference.

```
Object obj = new List<string> () { "dd", "ee" };
IEnumerable enumerable = obj as IEnumerable;
bool foundSomething = false;
foreach (var thing in enumerable)
{
    if(!foundSomething)
    {
        // Console.Write(thing.ToString()); If you want
        foundSomething = true;
        return thing;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question here, but if A is sealed, you can still write an extension method to iterate or handle the list.

[Extension methods for sealed class in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559551/extension-methods-for-sealed-class-in-c-sharp])

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface covariance to cast to `IEnumerable<object>` and then use some of LINQ's extension methods:

```
var aItems = (IEnumerable<object>) B.Foo();
Console.WriteLine(aItems.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

To get first element without touching anything you can do this:

```
object result = b.MethodThatReturnsList();
object firstEl = ((IList)result)[0];
```

Problem is that `firstEl`variable can only be `object` and you can't cast it to A because it is not accessible. Not very helpful though.

Here is the real problem: you can't declare public methods that return some private/internal types. You will get [this compilation error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be25s2h2.aspx).

Solution is to design a public interface that A will implement and return `List<IYourInterface>`. Another option is to have public base class.